# address the whole content of a section in css

Tags: html, css, scroll

I downloaded the code of this example on codrops

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ScrollingLayout/

As you can see , the background-attachment ( in this case image ) is fixed while any added text scrolls normally and each section gives an effect of overlapping the previous one. 
I want to make the whole content of that section stay fixed and let the next section overlap the previous one ( i.e the text should not scroll )

Here is the edited code -

```
    html, body, 
    .container,
    .scroller,
    .scroller section { 
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 0px;
    }
<!-- code to change below -->
    .scroller section {
        position: relative;
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .scroller section {
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
<!-- code to change above -->
    #section1 {
        background-image: url(../images/1.jpg);
    }
    #section2 {
        background-image: url(../images/2.jpg);
    }
    #section3 {
        background-image: url(../images/3.jpg);
    }
    #section4 {
        background-image: url(../images/4.jpg);
    }
    #section5 {
        background-image: url(../images/5.jpg);
}
```

Please suggest any way ( in css ) to make not only the background image but the whole text fixed in the position ( i.e how to address the whole content of a section in this css code )

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. I don't understand the behavior that you need. Maybe explain with some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to position the text fixed on the viewport. This can be achieved by adding this to your CSS for the text:

```
h1 { /* or whatever the selector is */
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  ...
}
```

This will make the element (in this case the `h1` element) will stay fixed on the page and will not scroll when you scroll the page down.